# call a asp.net vb function from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following error when trying to call a function in vb code from javascript (jquery)

In the view (.aspx) I have the following code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnRetirar" runat="server" OnClientClick="return alerteliminar();" IdEliminar='<%# Eval("CODIGO") %>'
                                                            ImageUrl="~/Images/ic_eliminar.gif" ToolTip="Borrar al Usuario Aprobador"></asp:ImageButton>
```

In the script I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function alerteliminar() {
        var letra="cancel";
        $("#texto").text("Seguro que desea Eliminar al usuario autorizador?");
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
               var id = $("#ctl00_ctphFrmContent_grvLista_ctl02_imgbtnRetirar").attr("ideliminar");
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "AprobadoresxModificacion.aspx/EliminarRegistro",
                    data: "{'Id':'" + id + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg)
                    }
                });
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
            $( this ).dialog("Eliminar");
            }
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
```

And in the vb code, I have the following:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Function EliminarRegistro(ByVal Id As Integer) As String
        Try
            If Me.BorrarAprobador(Integer.Parse(Id)) Then
                Me.btnBuscar_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
                Return "OK"
            Else
                Me.Mensaje("No se pudo borrar el registro")
                Return "BAD"
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function
```

The error I get is the following:
http://localhost:2091/WebSMEX/Paginas/Mantenimiento/AprobadoresxModificacion.aspx/EliminarRegistro 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: One possibility is that your `Id` parameter is `Integer`, but you are passing it in your JSON as a quoted string value: `data: "{'Id':'" + id + "'}"`.  Try removing the quotes around the value: `data: "{'Id':" + id + "}"`.

Comment: first, you need to understand that you are not calling VB.NET from jQuery. You calling a web method. You sending a request. And then asp.net knows how to invoke specific method. But there is no direct connection. Other than that, I know that error can occur in `BorrarAprobador` and `btnBuscar_Click` and `Mensaje`. Also, either stop this `Integer.Parse(Id)` or declare this `ByVal Id As String` - your JASON is quoted. Try `"{Id:" + id + "}"`

Comment: I tried in 2 ways, and I get the same error.

Comment: I personally don't like this: ` http://localhost:2091`. I like to create virtual directory. then I can debug only website/web method and call it via fiddler2. Once I see it works, I can think if my AJAX works

Answer (score 0):

Make sure VB method is `Shared`

`Public Shared Function EliminarRegistro(ByVal Id As Integer) As String`

Also make sure your class with the WebMethod inherits `System.Web.Services.WebService`

```
Public Class Service1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod(BufferResponse:=False)> _
    Public Function GetBigData() As DataSet
        'implementation code
    End Function
End Class
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: when I put Public Shared Function EliminarRegistro(ByVal Id As Integer) As String I get the following error: 'Me' is valid only within an instance method.

Comment: y Try, i get the following error: Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.

Comment: i use this: Dim vb As New Paginas_Mantenimiento_AprobadoresxModificacion
        Try
            If vb.BorrarAprobador(Integer.Parse(Id)) Then
                vb.btnBuscar_Click(Nothing, Nothing)
                Return "OK"
            Else
                vb.Mensaje("No se pudo borrar el registro")
                Return "BAD"
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.Message
        End Try --- and i get the same error

Comment: I don't think you can access `btnBuscar_Click` or `Mensaje` from a WebMethod

Comment: I tried just returning chains and gives me the same error. Only Return "OK".

Answer (score 0):

i need to do is add a ASP.Net AJAX ScriptManager to the page and set its EnablePageMethods property to true as shown below

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="400" EnableScriptGlobalization="True" EnablePageMethods="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```